# Far Manager with FarColorer plugin How to change change editor background color?

Tags: windows-10, colors, syntax-highlighting, far-manager, far-colorer

I use Far Manager 3.0 under Windows 10 x64, with Far Colorer plugin to highlight syntax ( in particular, in LaTex). Suddenly   the Editor background change color from the usual blue to white; I think I have not changed any settings. By background I mean the whole screen, i.e, the area without any text ( past the end of line or end of file), i.e if I open an empty file, I see a white screen with no text  .  How doI change the editor background color = whole sxreen, area without text (empty file), which used to be blue?

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings in `F9` » `Options` » `Plugins Configuration` » `FarColorer` » `Main settings` » `Color style`. Do you have maybe `White` instead of `Blue colors`?

If that doesn't fix the issue, I would delete the FarColorer settings. Find the filename in the `%appdata%/Far Manager/Profile/PluginsData/Descript.ion` (something like `D2F36B62-A470-418D-83A3-ED7A3710E5B5.db` in the same folder).